# Formatting negative fixed-length string

Tags: python

In `python`, I'm trying to format a number to be a fixed-length string with leading zeros, which can be done like so:

```
'{:0>10}'.format('10.0040')
'00010.0040'
```

I have a negative number and want to express the negative, I would get this:

```
'{:0>10}'.format('-10.0040')
'00-10.0040'
```

If I wanted to format the string to be:

```
'-0010.0040'
```

how could I do this?

I could do an if/then, but wondering if format would handle this already.

Comment: Huh. That's annoying.

Comment: Actually you're trying to format a *string* to be a fixed-length with leading zeros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're problem is that your "number" is being represented as a string, so python has no way of knowing whether it's positive or negative, because it doesn't know it's a number.

```
>>> '{: 010.4f}'.format(10.0400)
' 0010.0400'
>>> '{: 010.4f}'.format(-10.0400)
'-0010.0400'
```

This fills with `0`'s and has a fixed precision.  It will use a `space` for positive numbers and a `-` for negative.

You can change the behavior (i.e. `+` for positive signs, or just fill with an extra `0`) using the [`sign`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) portion of the formatting token

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do it with `str.format`.  May I propose using [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) instead?

```
>>> '-10.0040'.zfill(10)
'-0010.0040'
>>> '10.0040'.zfill(10)
'00010.0040'
```

If you can bear converting to a number before formatting:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> '{:010.4f}'.format(Decimal('10.0040'))
'00010.0040'
>>> '{:010.4f}'.format(Decimal('-10.0040'))
'-0010.0040'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can convert the string to a float, you can do this:

```
>>> '{:0=10.4f}'.format(float('-10.0040'))
'-0010.0040'
>>> '{:0=10.4f}'.format(float('10.0040'))
'00010.0040'
```